# Does jedis have a method that can take a partial key and returns all the values that match that partial key

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I have a requirement, where I have built up a key with two elements
clientid-systemid, using get, will return the value for that one key.

I also have a requirement where using a partial key clientid. I will return all values for that clientId.

Currently, I have it broken down into two calls to the cache.
Call 1 uses jedis.scan, this will return a list of all the keys of type clientid-systemid, prefixed with that clients Id.
I then call jedis.mget, and this returns all the values for that list of keys.

What I am trying to do is have it as one method call. I thought it was hscan or sscan.
But it looks as if they are not the correct calls.

Comment: Is that the only use case? if so why not just a list/hash for each clientid that will all the systemid?

Comment: So something like this, Map<SystemId, value> and it will be jedis..set(ClientId, map,bytes) I did think of that, but it means taking out a map then extracting the value from the map, just to return one value. I have a usecase where for clientid-systemid I return a value.
That is a las resort. I guess that there is not one  call to jedis then.

Comment: No, you should use the Hash API. `jedis.hset()/hget()`.

Comment: See: https://redis.io/commands/hset

Comment: Thank you looked at that. But now going in a different direction using mysql with awas. But thank you,